# How do I refresh UI on request?

Tags: c#, ajax

I've a Web app with a button that makes a call to an API to refresh data:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[Route("refreshFromService/{guid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage RefreshDataFromService(string guid)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(guid) && guid.Length == 36 && new Guid(guid) == new Guid("C943F8E4-647D-4044-B19E-4D97FA38EDE0"))
    {
        new AdData().RefreshCacheAdData(true);
        new JdeData().RefreshCacheJdeData(true);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
 }
```

Actually, it's an AJAX call, so in my Network Tab in Google Chrome, I see the request is in pending for 5 minutes.

How can I make this method an async method and how can I refresh my UI to show progress?

EDIT

When I refresh the page, I want the Progress Status to be updated.

Comment: Changing your method to `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RefreshDataFromService(string guid)` is not going to return control to your JS AJAX call. That is not how C# async works.. it is more about running multiple threads at the same time server-side

Comment: You have to refresh your Ui in the frontend after the request has finished, async in Backend can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it has nothing to do with a backend. So solution to your problem lies on frontend site. Ajax are asynchronous by nature so you can do something like that.

```
const loader = document.createElement('span')
// some styles for the loader

// i'm using body just for example purposes
document.body.appendChild(loader)

fetch('refreshFromService/{guid}')
  .then(data => {
    document.body.removeChild(loader)
    // do something with data
    return data
  })
```

Comment: Ok nice, but I think I have to change the backend because I want the Progress Status to update even if I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle it on UI like this:

```
 function getFlag() {

    var option = {
        url: '/controllerName/actionName',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    };

    $.ajax(option).success(function (data) {

        $("#picture").append("<img id=\"img1\" src=" + data.img_path + "\ />");

    });


};
```

I am using this code in UI for getting flags at runtime. So you need to write same type of code and get response from the backend. 
url: '/controllerName/actionName' is the controller in MVC and then action implemented in that controller. 
Request this method in UI with document.ready

I hope I have made sense to you. If still not clear write back i will explain further. 
Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, but when I will refresh the page, I will lose the Progress Status ?

Comment: do you want to upload some data or what?

Comment: No, I just want to update the progress status, even if I refresh the page

Comment: You need to set progress status in db from the backend, and when you load the page call it from db like i mentioned above.